# Running many python threads and grabbing the returns values of each

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

So i've had a look at several questions on SO, and also several webpages, and the python pages for `thread`, `threading`, and `multiprocessing`, but i can't seem to find anything that does what i want.

I've seen a few implementations which use queues, but they aren't really what i want either.

Is there a way i can do something like this:

```
hosts = "host1 host2 host3 host4 host5".split() #lazy but meh
cpuInfo = {}

threadPool = ThreadPool(processes=len(hosts))

def getCPUUsage(host):
  proc = Popen("ssh %s.rest.of.host.name top -bin 1" % host, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
  return proc.stdout.read()

for host in hosts:
  cpuInfo[host] = threadPool.newThread(getCPUUsage(host)).getFunctionReturnStuff())

threadPool.waitUntilFinished()

print cpuInfo # Some dictionary with a `top -bin 1` output for each host.
```

The only example i've seen so far uses a queue to get all the info out of the various threads by passing a `queue` as an argument to the function, and have the function manually add it's reutnr values to said queue - or they simply do not return anything and instead just `print` - which is useless to me.

Comment: Why aren't queues what you want? They seem to be EXACTLY what you're trying to accomplish. Remember when the function returns, it'll return its value to the Thread. If you want its Thread to report that value back to the main thread you'll have to use some sort of messaging e.g. queues or etc.

Comment: @AdamSmith Well for one, if i do this, then how can i use any old function in the thread, if they all have to know to return to the queue?

Comment: By writing every function that needs to work threadwise to work as it if were a thread ;) `def foo(q, *args): result=dostuff(args); q.put(result)`

Comment: @AdamSmith is there really no way this can be done automatically?

Comment: I can't comment on whether there's no way for you to write a thread that returns a value to another thread automatically. Personally I would write a class that inherits `Thread` to do that if you were going to do a lot of it, but that keeps you from using `ThreadPool`.

Comment: I've actualyl found a method that's much easier, i'll put it as an answer once i'm done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example starts one worker per CPU on the computer.  For each hostname in a list, it tells a worker to ssh to that computer, run a command, and return the result to original caller.  In my case I'm just ssh'ing once into my laptop, but you get the idea.

```
import multiprocessing, subprocess

def get_value(args):
    hostname = args[0]
    return subprocess.check_output(
        'ssh {} hostname'.format(hostname),
        shell=True,
        )

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
print list( pool.imap_unordered(
    get_value,
    [ ('localhost',) ],
    ) )
```

Example output from my lappytop:

```
['palabras\n']
```

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: This is more or less exactly how I did it, except I used `pool.map` rather than `imap`. What's the difference?

Comment: `map` returns things in order. In general I don't care about the order, I'd rather see something sooner, so my default is `imap_unordered`.

Comment: Aah. yah that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, here's what I'd do:

```
class MessagingThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue=None, **kwds):
        super(MessagingThread, self).__init__(**kwds)
        self.value = None
        self.queue = queue
    def run(self):
        """Method representing the thread's activity.

        You may override this method in a subclass. The standard run() method
        invokes the callable object passed to the object's constructor as the
        target argument, if any, with sequential and keyword arguments taken
        from the args and kwargs arguments, respectively.

        """
        try:
            if self._target:
                self.value = self._target(*self._args, **self.kwargs)
                self.queue.put(self.value)
        finally:
            # Avoid a refcycle if the thread is running a function with
            # an argument that has a member that points to the thread.
            del self._target, self._args, self._kwargs
```